# Logistic regression - residual sum of square

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics

In Elements of Statistical Learning https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Section 4.4.3 about Logistic Regression infers from the Newton-Raphson procedure for fitting linear logistic model a relationship between so-called adjusted response $z_{i}$ and maximum-likelihood parameter estimates $\hat{\beta}$ :

$z_{i}=x_{i}^{T}\hat{\beta}+\frac{(y_{i}-\hat{p_{i}})}{\hat{p_{i}}(1-\hat{p_{i}})}$

This stems directly from the expression of adjusted response in the expression of the Newton step in the previous section :

$\textbf{z}=\textbf{X}\beta^{old}+\textbf{W}^{-1}(\textbf{y}-\textbf{p})$

It is then said, equation 4.30

> The weighted residual sum-of-squares is the familiar Pearson chisquare statistic
>   $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{(y_{i} − \hat{p}_{i})^{2}}{
> \hat{p}_{i}(1 − \hat{p}_{i})}$
>   a quadratic approximation to the deviance.

- Why isn't the residual sum of squares $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{(y_{i} − \hat{p}_{i})^{2}}{
  (\hat{p}_{i}(1 − \hat{p}_{i}))^{\textbf{2}}}$ ?
- How do we justify that the sum "follows" a Chisquare statistics ?
- Why would this give a quadratic approximation of the deviance ? ( deviance is defined as $-2\times$ loglikelihood )
- How is this result convenient ?

References to good books/texts in statistics around those topics are welcome.